# Datatables fnOpen: click is not triggered within html

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have followed the guide at http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/row_details.html

```
/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails ( nTr , data_id )
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "/data/" + data_id,
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) { 
      var sOut = '<table cellpadding="7" cellspacing="2" border="0" style="margin-left:50px;">';
      sOut += '<thead><tr><th></th><th>Notes</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < msg.length; ++index)
      {
        sOut += "<tr>" +
          "<td></td>" +
          "<td><textarea name='notes' class='autosave form-control' data-id='" + msg[index]['id'] + "'>" + msg[index]['notes'] + "</textarea></td>" +
          "</tr>";
      }

      sOut += '</tbody>';
      sOut += '<tfoot><tr><td colspan="6"><div class="btn btn-default addnewrow">Add new Row</div></td></tr></tfoot></table>';
      $('.table_production_log').dataTable().fnOpen( nTr, sOut, msg[0]['job_assign_id'] );
    }

  });  

}
```

The problem that i have is that an onclick event is not triggered when I click on .addnewrow

```
$('body').on('click', '.addnewrow', function () {
  // create new row in database, we need job assign id
  var sOut =  "<tr>" +
      "<td><img src='http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/examples_support/details_close.png' /></td>" + 
      "<td><textarea name='notes' class='autosave form-control' data-id='" + msg[index]['id'] + "'>" + msg[index]['notes'] + "</textarea></td>" +
      "</tr>";

  $(this).parent().find('tr:last').after(sOut); 
});
```

Even if I put alert $('body').on('click', '.addnewrow', function () { alert("123"); }); I get nothing back.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: You probably need to use the `fnRowCallback` callback to bind the click event

Comment: Hi. Qthanks for reply. I am not sure on how TO connect fnRowCallback with my issue. The button I have problem with is within html that is added to the table using fnOpen... I have another input field with $.on('input')  which works fine, but this alarticular button doesn't, not even an HTML onclick does nothing

Comment: I'll bet your `$('body').on('click', '.addnewrow', function () {` is inside a `ready` function or similar, that this basically is a scope problem.

Comment: thanks for reply. the onclick action is not inside any function. Issue is related to the button it self, if i was to change <div> to be <button> or <input> onclick triggered fine.